# System Volume Information folder space

Tags: backup, directory, disk-usage, system, storage

I have 30TB of space in Ubuntu 20.04. I'm using it as a backup storage and I have 16TB of space total data. Some day I found backup was not completed because "ran out of space" in the backup storage. I used "Incremental" backup, so I didn't think it's full. I found "system volume information" folders ate rest of the space. How can I setup without store too much "system vilume information"?

Comment: please [edit] your question to indicate which backup client you are using - such déjà dup, rsync rtc